# Null point (vector) between n point charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields

I have derived the result for 2 positive charges, and for one positive one negative can be obtained by using the minus sign correctly. But I was unable to extend it or solve for n charges. Is my extension right? (I have maintained dimensions and extended it that's all)
Or what is the correct derivation for it?
[image]

Comment: How about you walk us through the logic you used to arrive at your answer for the 2-charge case, and we can discuss whether it generalizes to more charges.  Or maybe easier: how do you check if you're right in the 2-charge case?

Comment: Oh, I simply equated the magnitude of force and opposed the direction of force by the 2 charges. It does work for the 2 charges. But I don't know about multiple ones.